# Calling function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, typescript, react-native

I have this function:

```js
public getPermissions() {
  const { listItems } = this.state;

  {listItems.length > 0 && listItems.map((item: Project) => {
    let web = new Web(item.ListUrl);

    web.getCurrentUserEffectivePermissions().then(perms => { 
      if (web.hasPermissions(perms, PermissionKind.ViewPages)) {
        return item.Title
      } else {
        return console.log('NOT Access');
      }
    }
```

I try to call this function inside a React component:

```js
public render() {
  return (
    <div>  ///error message
      {this.getPermissions()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, I get an error message for the first div:

```
"[ts]
Type '{ children: void; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Type '{ children: void; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>"
```

What does this error mean? How can I call the getPermissions function in the render function?

Comment: you arent returning a jsx element. un the render return you need to return jsx

Comment: That would solve the error message... however, `getPermission` has syntax errors by itself. You only need to wrap code into curly brackets when they are wrapped within JSX (beside the scope thing, but that's not that relevant now) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method doesn't return JSX. You should call these kinds of events on lifecycle methods or you can simply call it before `return` of `render()` method like:

```
render() {
  this.getPermissions();

  return (...)
}
```

or in `componentDidMount` (much better then calling in render()) lifecyle like:

```
    class YourComponent extends Component {  
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { listItems: ... };
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.getPermissions();
      }

      getPermissions = () => {
        const { listItems } = this.state;

        {listItems.length > 0 && listItems.map((item: Project) => {
          let web = new Web(item.ListUrl);

          web.getCurrentUserEffectivePermissions().then(perms => { 
            if (web.hasPermissions(perms, PermissionKind.ViewPages)) {
             return item.Title
            } else {
              return console.log('NOT Access');
            }
         }
      }

      render() {
        return (...)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped me alot. :) Teşekkür.